# How do I change the color of the filter icon when the Filter and Reset buttons are pressed?

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a table with a Filter icon in each column.

```
<thead>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="col in vm.columns">
                <a href="javascript:;" ng-click="vm.open(col)"> <i class="fa fa-filter"></i></a>                    
                    {{col.name}}
                    <span ng-show="vm.filters['AscendingBy'+col.name]"></span>
                </a>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

When I click on it, I get different popups that allow me to filter the data. I need to click on the Filter button, change the color of the icon, but only for the current column, and when I click the Reset, it returns the color to the original one

```
<div class="transactions-filter-modal-footer">
<a style="cursor: pointer" ng-click="vm.close()">Reset</a>
<button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="vm.confirm()">Filter</button>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished using [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass).

According to the docs:

> The result of the evaluation can be a string
>   representing space delimited class names, an array, or a map of class
>   names to boolean values. In the case of a map, the names of the
>   properties whose values are truthy will be added as css classes to the
>   element.

In your function that sets/resets the filter, you can set a flag for whichever filter is being applied and use ng-class to conditionally apply a class to the element based on the value of the flag, or (in the inefficient example below), on the return value of a function.

```
<thead>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="col in vm.columns"
                ng-class="isFiltered(col)">
                <a href="javascript:;" ng-click="vm.open(col)"> <i class="fa fa-filter"></i></a>                    
                    {{col.name}}
                    <span ng-show="vm.filters['AscendingBy'+col.name]"></span>
                </a>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
```